# c# windows form - How to make add entry on website after click button

Tags: c#, windows, forms, web, httprequest

Hello i doing a little app for my training programming. I am 1 day learner :D.

I want to make generator post in my forum. I created simple generator, now i want to make post into website from application.

```
http://localhost/web/newthread.php?fid=5 <-- Its link to post website

<input type="text" class="textbox" name="subject" size="40" maxlength="85" value="" tabindex="1"> Its  place for Title on website

<body contenteditable="true" dir="ltr" class=" placeholder"><p><br></p></body> <-- Its place for entry

<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Napisz wątek" tabindex="4" accesskey="s"> <-- Its button to post
```

Now...

When i click Button5 in my app

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Want to.

1. Go to Link (Link to post website)
2. Copy Text from "textBox1_tytul"  windows app to Place title on the Website
3. Copy Text from "textBox1_output"  windows app to Place for entry on the Website
4. Click Button to post on the website
5. Show in my windows app Alert "Entry added"

   string message = "Entry added";
   MessageBox.Show(message);

I am beginner and i dont know how to make it... any help, sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would have to better use a class HttpClient.
for example i copy a piece of a code from
https://zetcode.com/csharp/httpclient/
I mean it that you have to make a  Http request by  HttpClient.
i hope i could have understanded you probmlem and help you

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var person = new Person("John Doe", "gardener");

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
using var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(result);

record Person(string Name, string Occupation);
```